# "high-end clientele" is to "low-end clientele" as "carriage trade" is to what?

Tags: phrase-requests, antonyms, idiom-requests

Is there a phrase in English that works as a direct antonym to the idiomatic [***carriage trade***](https://www.google.fr/search?q=carriage+trade&prmd=smivn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8ruHeuerKAhVGSBQKHVDMD_UQ_AUICSgD), that is, the wealthy patrons of a store, restaurant, hotel, etc.; the elite clientele?

> **carriage trade**: [mass noun] *North American informal*
>   The wealthy clientele of a business:
>   *determined to pursue the carriage trade, she quickly established an old-girl network* (Source: ODO)
>
> [**carriage**](https://www.google.fr/search?q=caleche+hermes&biw=497&bih=328&prmd=sinv&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjshKHsr-vKAhUKuhoKHdyaCWcQ_AUIBygC#tbm=isch&q=caleche): A wheeled vehicle, especially a four-wheeled horse-drawn passenger vehicle, often of an elegant design. (Source: AHD)

Comment: 'Direct antonym' could be either the vast majority of customers who do not have their clothes made to measure, or the impecunious who only buy T-shirts if they are not full price: which do you want?

Comment: *Carriage trade* is on its way out, to that imaginary place where *lowscale clientele* also doesn't exist. Here's a neat [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bargain+basement%2Cbargain+hunters%2Ccarriage+trade%2Cupscale+clientele%2Clowscale+clientele&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbargain%20basement%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbargain%20hunters%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccarriage%20trade%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cupscale%20clientele%3B%2Cc0) comparing some of these answers and your words. (click search again: "Ngrams not found: lowscale clientele")

Comment: That Ngram is rather interesting in that "carriage trade" rises just as people with means were buying automobiles.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I just came across the answer to my own question while searching the Net.

*high-end clientele* is to *low-end clientele* as *carriage trade* is to ***coach trade***.

> *The railroad recognizes that the change in dining car patronage from the carriage trade to the coach trade necessarily shifts the emphasis from high-priced meals to lower-priced dishes* [Railway Age - Volume 146 - Page 27](https://books.google.fr/books?id=as8lAAAAMAAJ&q=%22the+railroad+recognizes+that+the+change%22&dq=%22the+railroad+recognizes+that+the+change%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdpLqHhuvKAhWKuxQKHSHrAw8Q6AEIHTAA)
>
> **coach class**: *n.* An economical class of passenger accommodations on a commercial airplane or other conveyance. [American Heritage® Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/coach+class)
>
> **coach**: A large, closed, four-wheeled carriage with an elevated exterior seat for the driver; a stagecoach. [American Heritage® Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/coach)

Comment: I'm not sure *carriage trade* ever had much currency (but it's primarily AmE, so what do I know?). But if we call them "customers" rather than "trade", here are a few contexts explicitly contrasting ["wealthy customers" and "coach customers"](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=vDy6VoT8MobW8Af454z4DQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22wealthy+customers%22+%22coach+customers%22), so there's no question in my mind that ***coach*** is the word you seek.

Answer (score 17):

I came across the phrase ***[bargain-basement](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bargain%E2%80%93basement)*** while researching for an appropriate answer.

> (adj.) markedly inexpensive (bargain–basement rates)

[Merriam Webster]

From *[The 8 Steps: Your Business or Your Life - Getting All You Want Out of BOTH:: By David Shepherd](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=xhOK0PCKG3YC&pg=PT52&dq=%22carriage+trade%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-vO7WxurKAhVQcY4KHS3yDlo4ChDoAQg3MAc#v=onepage&q&f=false)*, customers can be broadly classified into 4 groups (The Harvard Model):

[image]

Thus, I feel ***bargain-basement customers*** would better suit your context.

Answer (score 11):

I would suggest **mass market**. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_market):

> The **mass market** is the largest group of end consumers for a specified product. It is the opposite of the term **niche market**.

The carriage trade is a niche market, but obviously there are other niche markets, so if you want a term to use in isolation (i.e. not mentioning carriage trade) then it wouldn't fit well. But it would work well in e.g.:

> Most shops maximise their profits by aiming at the mass market: *"pile 'em high and sell 'em cheap"*. Some, however, manage to make more money by aiming at the carriage trade, by selling fewer items but selling each one at a significantly higher profit.

Answer (score 9):

The term ***[budget](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/budget)*** is used to refer to customers who generally have a limited and predetermied amount of money to spend. Without referring to  low-social classes, I'd say that ***"budget customers"*** are those that may convey the idea  of low, careful and restricted spending, just opposite to what  the  big spenders,  like the "carriage trade", convey.

Budget:

> - the amount of money that is available for, required for, or assigned to a particular purpose.

(M-W)

Answer (score 6):

It's not an exact match, but you could consider using "Trade (business) with **bargain hunters**." A [bargain hunter](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bargain-hunter) means:

> a ​person who looks for a ​place to ​buy something at a ​price that is
>   ​cheaper than usual.

[Cambridge Dictionaries Online]

Comment: A rich big spender may well be, and probably often is, a bargain hunter.

Comment: @Josh61 Yes, you are right, but usually bargain hunters are not upscale clientele who pursue carriage trade.

Answer (score 0):

my first reaction was "hoi-polloi", but coach trade seems a more fitting antonym.

originally from Greek meaning "masses". Merriam Webster has several definitions along the lines of "majority"